# Xpath - Find parent Attribute using child condition

Tags: xpath, ssis

Need some help.I am using XML task in SSIS.

In the below example, I am trying to find the ID's of all those books whos price >20 .
If I use `//book[price > '20']/self::*/attribute::id` I am able to get the values like
`bk101bk108bk109` . How can i get the solution like

```
bk101
bk108
bk109
```

What can be the solution for this ? Is there a better way to get the result than what I am trying ?
The Xpath operation in XML task is set to "Values"

```
<catalog>
           <book id="bk101">
              <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
              <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
              <genre>Computer</genre>
              <price>44.95</price>
              <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
              <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
              with XML.</description>
           </book>
           <book id="bk102">
              <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
              <title>Midnight Rain</title>
              <genre>Fantasy</genre>
              <price>5.95</price>
              <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
              <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
              an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
              of the world.</description>
           </book>
    </catalog>
```

[image]

Comment: How are you storing the results? If i output the result to a `variable` or `xml file` i'm getting it in different row

Comment: You may put for loop before you query and return it. for $x in //book[price > '20']/self::*/data(attribute::id) return <p>{$x}</p>

Comment: Praveen - I am storing the result in XML file.

Comment: which statement produced the output - `bk101bk108bk109`? give us that code.

Comment: SC is now attached.
//book[price > '20']/self::*/attribute::id  or //book[price > '20']/@id  gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the index:

```
//book[price > '20'][1]/@id
//book[price > '20'][2]/@id
//book[price > '20'][3]/@id
```

Comment: Nora, I am afraid that the solution proposed won't help. There can be 1000's of ID's. The equation here is - how to add a virual CR LF ? I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using XML task, we can use Foreach NodeList Enumerator and within it a script task to
to enter the values.  I just did it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you need - watch this video how to handle XML in SSIS: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXDexFNj44M

2) this xPath will return id's of books with price greater than 20:

```
//book/price[text() > 20]/../@id
```